# How do I make a pixel transparent in a TBitmap where the pixel format is pf32bit?

Tags: delphi

I'm upgrading the button images in a Delphi application.  I have several bitmaps where the transparency is represented by `clFushia`.  I'm trying variations on

```
procedure TForm6.MakeTransparent(bmp: TBitmap);
type
  PRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = array[Word] of TRGBQuad;
var
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  line: PRGBQuadArray;
  Alpha : TRGBQuad;
begin
  Alpha.rgbBlue := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbGreen := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbRed := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbReserved := $00;
  bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  for x := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
  begin
    for y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
    begin
      if bmp.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] = clFuchsia then
      begin
        line := bmp.ScanLine[y];
        line[x] := Alpha;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But when I do `bmp.Save`, the image lacks transparency.  What am I doing wrong here?

For more background, I have a couple of long bitmaps made up of many 16x16 and 32x32 glyphs, which I'm attempting to convert using:

```
procedure TForm6.ExtractImages(x: TBitmap);
var
  SourceRect: TRect;
  I: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  DestinationRect: TRect;
  wh: integer; //width, height
  FileName: string;
begin
  wh := x.Height;
  SourceRect := Rect(0, 0, wh, wh);
  for I := 0 to x.Width div wh do
  begin
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.Width := wh;
    bmp.Height := wh;
    bmp.PixelFormat := Images16bmp.PixelFormat;

    DestinationRect := Rect(i * wh, 0, (i + 1) * wh - 1, wh - 1);
    bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(SourceRect, x.Canvas, DestinationRect);

    MakeTransparent(bmp);
    FileName := Format('%d\%d.bmp', [wh, i]);
    bmp.SaveToFile('D:\Temp\SplitImages\' + FileName);
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

And I'm calling:

```
ExtractImages(Images16BMP);
ExtractImages(Images32BMP);
```

Where `Images16BMP` is a 2500x16 bitmap and `Images32BMP` is 5000x32 bitmap. I'm using Delphi XE8.

Comment: I think I'd be using a different tool to do this. Why would you choose delphi? You'll also have low quality results no matter because you won't have partial transparency.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes you are probably correct - a tool like Convert would probably have solved this easily.  If only I could have installed it on a highly firewalled VM.

Comment: You don't need anything to be installed. You just need to run executables. Which has got to be easier than installing an entire dev department. It's also tragic that this is the only computer you have. A highly firewalled VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to get Remy's solution working in Delphi XE8 (may work in later versions of Delphi, but I haven't tested).  I think transparent BMPs are not well supported - PNGs on the other hand seem to work much better.

Here is what I ended up doing

```
procedure TForm6.CopyTransparent(Source: TBitmap; Destination: TPngImage);
var
  x, y: integer;
begin
  for y := 0 to Source.Height-1 do
  begin
    for x := 0 to Source.Width-1 do
    begin
      if Source.Canvas.Pixels[x, y] <> clFuchsia then
      begin
        Destination.Pixels[x, y] := Source.Canvas.Pixels[x, y];
        Destination.AlphaScanline[y][x] := 255; //make pixel opaque
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm6.ExtractImages(MultiWide: TBitmap);
var
  SourceRect: TRect;
  I: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  DestinationRect: TRect;
  wh: integer; //width, height
  FileName: string;
  png: TPngImage;
begin
  wh := MultiWide.Height;
  SourceRect := Rect(0, 0, wh, wh);
  for I := 0 to MultiWide.Width div wh do //for every sub-image
  begin
    png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA, 8, wh, wh);

    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.Width := wh;
    bmp.Height := wh;
    bmp.PixelFormat := Images16bmp.PixelFormat;
    DestinationRect := Rect(i * wh, 0, (i + 1) * wh - 1, wh - 1);
    bmp.Canvas.CopyRect(SourceRect, MultiWide.Canvas, DestinationRect); //copy the sub-image to bmp

    CopyTransparent(bmp, png);

    FileName := Format('%d\%d.png', [wh, i]);
    png.SaveToFile('D:\Temp\SplitImages\' + FileName);
    bmp.Assign(png);
    FileName := Format('%d\%d.bmp', [wh, i]);
    png.SaveToFile('D:\Temp\SplitImages\' + FileName);

    png.Free;
    bmp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I'm creating a transparent PNG, then copying the non-Fuchsia pixels from the bitmap to the PNG and making them opaque.  From there I can save the PNG, and assign it to the BMP, and magically I have a transparent bitmap.  This gave me 16x16 and 32x32 transparent BMPs and PNGs saved to disk.  And yes, I am using the slow Pixels property - but the code executes in less than a second for more than 300 images.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `TBitmap.AlphaFormat` property to `afDefined` to specify the alpha channel is being used. By default, the alpha channel is ignored.

On a side note, don't use the slow `Canvas.Pixels` property to scan all of the pixels, especially since you are already using the `Scanline` property anyway. Use the `Scanline` to scan pixels as well as manipulate them.

```
procedure TForm6.MakeTransparent(bmp: TBitmap);
type
  PRGBQuadArray = ^TRGBQuadArray;
  TRGBQuadArray = array[Word] of TRGBQuad;
var
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  line: PRGBQuadArray;
  Pixel, Alpha : TRGBQuad;
  rgb: DWORD;
begin
  rgb := ColorToRGB(clFuchsia);

  Pixel.rgbBlue := GetBValue(rgb);
  Pixel.rgbGreen := GetGValue(rgb);
  Pixel.rgbRed := GetRValue(rgb);
  Pixel.rgbReserved := $00;

  Alpha.rgbBlue := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbGreen := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbRed := $FF;
  Alpha.rgbReserved := $00;

  bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
  for y := 0 to bmp.Height-1 do
  begin
    line := bmp.ScanLine[y];
    for x := 0 to bmp.Width-1 do
    begin
      if line[x] = Pixel then
      begin
        line[x] := Alpha;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  bmp.AlphaFormat := afDefined;
end;
```